# Is there a way to use a variable from another file in a php include?

Tags: php, string, file, include

So basically I have a file, lets say `file1.php` and it includes another `file2.php`.

`file1.php` contains a variable called `$dateString` that I have performed some operations on.

`file2.php` also has the same variable called `$dateString` however this variable is not being referenced within this include file even though `$dateString` was initialized prior to including `file2.php`.

So this is currently how `file1.php` looks like:

```
$dateString = 'some expression';

include 'file2.php';
```

`file2.php` is basically trying to echo out the variable that was initialized in `file1.php`

```
echo $dateString;
```

Everything else from `file2.php` is being called properly except that one variable.

Hopefully this makes sense. Is this possible in PHP? I have read in other places that you need to make the variables global and others have mentioned how you cant reference a variable from a parent file within a child file..any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? You have PHP and variables and include etc. Nothing bad will happen to you trying it ;)

Comment: This should work as it is. When PHP includes a file, it effectively pastes the code from the included file into the calling file, so the included file can access variables from the one that calls it. You'll only need to make it a global variable if it's being accessed inside a function.

Comment: I did try it. I've tried it a million different ways that's why I was asking if there is maybe something that I am missing in terms of concepts or lack of knowledge on my part

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing magically happening when you use PHP's `include()`. the included file's code is basically just inserted at the point where you are including it - resulting in one bigger PHP file.
it doesn't really matter if the "parent" or in the "child" file - it's the position that matters since PHP will parse the single resulting file from top to bottom.

for example: if you set the variable in file A before including file B, file B will know about the variable. but if you set the variable in file A after including file B - file B doesn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

With coding you should always try and test your own things before asking other people, butch like what @bub suggested in the comments.

Variables are global pretty much, you are able to include another file and use variables that are in file1.php in file2.php.

Otherwise, if you are using them in a function, I'd suggest using:

```
global $var;
```

the above should only be used in a function.